# Solution (numerical or symbolic) of functional equations?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Can I solve functional equations with Mathematica? How?

For example, I am trying to solve:

$$\frac{F(x)}{F(1)} = 2F\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{4a}\right)-F(x/a)$$

for specific values of $a$. Can Mathematica help me? I would be happy with a numerical solution.

Comment: As far as I've been able to tell, you solve these kinds of equations in *Mathematica* the same way you would do them by hand: by finding some transformation that turns the equation into a recurrence relation or a differential equation or a algebraic equation, and solve that instead. There are various "tricks" you can find online just by searching "solve functional equations".

Comment: @march I have tried looking but didn't find any.

Comment: The equation yields4 `F[1/a] == 1`, if that is of help.